# I am not able to migrate mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I connected two databases in my project PostgreSQL and MySQL. In MySQL, I have my all models in the models folder. So I want to migrate them that I can see tables in the MySQL database and put some data in it.

When I run the migrate first then there is the table name called `django_migrations` is created. And whenever check my databases using MySQL Command Line then this is the only table I see.

I don't know why I am not able to see my other tables. I want to know what am I doing wrong that my PMS database is not migrating.

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations pms` then this is showing:

```
Migrations for 'pms':
  pms\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Assignment
    - Create model BankAccount
    - Create model City
    - Create model Country
    - Create model House
    - Create model HouseOffering
    - Create model HouseOwnership
    - Create model Invoice
    - Create model InvoiceItem
    - Create model InvoiceParticipation
    - Create model InvoicePaymentParticipation
    - Create model Lease
    - Create model Locality
    - Create model Payment
    - Create model PaymentAdjustment
    - Create model PaymentBill
    - Create model PmsSubscription
    - Create model Society
    - Create model TenantRentPaymentBill
    - Create model User
```

And after that when I migrate `python manage.py migrate --database=pms` this is showing:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_results, pms, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'django': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': DJANGO_DB_HOST,
        'PORT': DJANGO_DB_PORT,
        'USER': DJANGO_DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD,
        'NAME': DJANGO_DB_NAME,
    },
    'pms': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': PMS_DB_HOST,
        'PORT': PMS_DB_PORT,
        'USER': PMS_DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': PMS_DB_PASSWORD,
        'NAME': PMS_DB_NAME,
    }
}
```

**Update!**

models/country.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    beats_database_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='beatsDatabaseId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'countries'
```

When I comment `managed = False` then this error is showing:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_results, pms, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying pms.0003_alter_country_table...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'azuro.countries' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 469, in database_forwards
    new_model._meta.db_table,
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 452, in alter_db_table
    "new_table": self.quote_name(new_db_table),
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\python\Azuro\azurovenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'azuro.countries' doesn't exist")
```

I don't know what is happening, it's my time that I'm using MySQL with Django.

Please help me!!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's likely that that PMS database already has a (bad) migration record for possibly an earlier version of that migration. Try `python manage.py showmigrations --database=pms`.

Comment: above command is showing this:
`admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length`

Comment: But why it is not migrating models?

Comment: makemigrations makes the `migration_*.py` files in migrations folder, `migrate` sync the database, if `No migrations to apply.`  is shown that means the db is in sync with the migrations

Comment: Can you try recreating your database (or removing the django_migration table ?)

Comment: @Sami Tahri
Yes, I did but not worked.